# "Skinny", "Scrawny" and "Bony"

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

According to the dictionaries, the words **Skinny**, **Scrawny** and **Boney** mean so close that I cannot distinguish between them. They all mean **very thin** and even showing bones! I was wondering if you could let me know how would you interpret them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, there is so little difference in perceived meaning it is barely worth pondering over. They do all have individual and differing dictionary definitions, but they are so similar that in general usage they would mostly be perceived to have the same meaning - like calling someone an "idiot", "moron", or "imbecile" all imply stupidity yet at one time these were all associated with intelligence quotations and could be ranked.

The only thing I would say is that "skinny" does not by definition mean that a person's bones are visibly showing, whereas "scrawny" and "bony" (*not usually spelled with an 'e', but apparently not incorrect*) do. Also "skinny" *can* imply someone is unhealthily thin, but not necessarily - someone can with a good metabolism can be skinny, yet healthy. With the other two there is an inference that something is wrong, perhaps undernourishment - nobody's bones should be showing.

Answer (score 2):

This applies to American English, and more specifically to me as the interpretation is nuanced to the point of being subjective. Other natural speakers from other countries or even the same country may answer differently.

**Boney**/**Bony**, when describing a person, either means so skinny that they show bones, or their bones are particularly pointy and show even if they aren't very skinny (think sharp elbows/heels/shoulders).

**Scrawny**, I would argue, is a step above being **bony**. The person is skinny, with an extra emphasis on a lack of muscle definition. I typically see/hear it used to establish a degree of physical fitness, and is definitely a negative adjective.

> He was 6'4", jacked, and bullied all of the scrawny kids.

**Skinny** can be applied in a wide range of physiques and appearances. One person could be fit and skinny while another person could be borderline-starvation skinny. The common factor is that both people do not have much body fat.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *skinny* is less serious sounding than *scrawny*. When I hear *skinny*, I do not automatically imagine being able to see someone's bones. *Skin and bones* is another way to say *very skinny*. Also, *scrawny* is a common collocate of *cat*. Finally, *boney* is not used quite as much as *skinny* and puts an emphasis on being able to see someones bones. For example, "I have very boney wrists." It's not so much that they are *skinny* (plus, it's about the wrist bone protrusion), but that the bone is prominent. Hope that helps!